# Best Way to Address: Semi overlapping view containing RecyclerView acting as drawer

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the best way to address this layout? view 2 should be semi placed over view 1, showing part of the RecyclerView. When user tap on that and slide right, view 2 slides over view 1 until a predefined margin. Is it possible to achieve that using NavigationDrawer?

[image]

Comment: Use negative margins, and you can apply this to any view

Comment: I can set negative margin for NavigationDrawer and be able to pull it then?